# Java - Passing an object as a parameter in a constructor... from a superclass

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, subclass, superclass

I have these classes: an abstract class called "Shape", a class Point extends Shape, and a class Circle extends Point

I can't change this relationship. 
What I need to do is create a constructor in Circle which receives as parameters an object Point and a double. I already created an object Point, called point 
I already tried this:

```
public Circle (Point objPunto, double valorRadio){   
  Pointp = new Point(objPunto.getX(), objPunto.getY());
  setRadio(valorRadio);}
```

and

```
Circulo circulo2 = new Circulo(point, 3);
```

but it doesn't seem to work.It shows me this: 
`Implicit super constructor Punto() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor`.

I also tried some weird things using Super, but that didn't work either. I'm starting to think that it can be done, and if so... anyone knows why?

Thanks!

Code for Point

```
    public class Point extends Shape {

   private int x;  
   private int y;  

   public Point( int valorX, int valorY ){
      x = valorX;  
      y = valorY;  
   } 

   public void setX( int valorX ){
      x = valorX;  
   } 

   public int getX(){
      return x;
   } 

   public void setY( int valorY ){
      y = valorY;  
   } 

   public int getY(){
      return y;
   } 

   public String getName(){
      return "Punto";
   } 

   public String describe(){
      return "[" + obtenerX() + ", " + obtenerY() + "]";
   } 
}
```

Comment: Is it a compiler error? What error does the compiler says?

Comment: this one: Implicit super constructor Point() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor

Comment: With the error you are getting I am assuming that you must call the super class for some reason. Can you post the code of the other two classes please. Or at least the constructor

Comment: what is the constructor for point?

Comment: this one's the one from the superclass

Comment: public class Point extends Shape{
 
   private int x;  
   private int y;  

   public Point( int valorX, int valorY ){
      x = valorX;  
      y = valorY;  
   }

Comment: This one's from the abstract class: 
public abstract class Shape extends Object
{
   public double getArea(){
      return 0.0;
   } 

   public double getVolume(){
      return 0.0;
   } 

   public abstract String getName();

   public abstract String Describe();

}

Comment: gonna post he whole code for Point in the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just call `super()` for first two arguments as below:

```
    public Circle (Point objPunto, double valorRadio){   
      super(objPunto.getX(), objPunto.getY());
      setRadio(valorRadio);
    }
```

`super()` calls the constructor of the `parent class` and it should be the first statement inside the child constructor, if used.

Comment: public Circulo (Punto objPunto, double valorRadio){   
    super(objPunto.obtenerX(), objPunto.obtenerY());
      establecerRadio(valorRadio);
   }

Comment: @margseo: It looks OK. Is there any issue?

Answer (score 2):

Your circle is trying to call `super();` as it's first step, but `Point` doesn't have a default no-arg constructor.  You have to call the super method that takes parameters as the first line of your Circle's constructor.

Try `super(objPunto.getX(), objPunto.getY());` as the first call in the Circle constructor

Answer (score 0):

If your class `Circle` extends `Point`, then it can access it's members.
There's no need to create a `new Point()`:

```
public Circle (Point objPunto, double valorRadio){   
  setX(objPunto.getX());
  setY(objPunto.getY());
  setRadio(valorRadio);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the info you just gave, you should do something like this

```
public Circle (Point objPunto, double valorRadio) {
    super.(objPunto.getX(), objPunto.getY());
}
```

Make you sure you understand when to call the super class' constructor though. Remember that when you are extending, it still creates the super classes, meaning if there is any information they need to create itself then you need to call super. And its important to note that super **MUST** be the first thing you call if you do.